# How to programmatically open iOS Facebook app with pre-populated status?

Tags: ios, facebook, url

Is there a URL scheme to open the Facebook iOS app, with a pre-made status in the box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. There is a `fb://publish/?text=<your text here>"` URI scheme (see [Question 6813279](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813279/how-to-pass-parameters-to-facebook-fb-publish) and the [pertinent entry in the akosma wiki](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)). The problem is that it does not redirect to the sharing view used by current versions of the Facebook app (as of version 3.4, I think – left / first screenshot), but rather to the older, simplistic one used before that (right / second screenshot).

[image: Facebook app sharing screen – new style]
[image: Facebook app sharing screen – old style]